Deleting questions on the same topic within every 1 week window
I have a spreadsheet. In one column, there are questions. In the next column, there are topics. In the third column, there are dates. The data are sorted by date.
I want to ensure that, in EVERY one week period, there are no two questions on the same topic (ignoring the topic 'other', which is an exception). For example, in the first week (starting from the earliest date in the dataset), there should be no two questions on the same topic. Likewise, in the week starting from the second oldest date,  there should be no two questions on the same topic.
I tried to automate this in Python using the code below. However, it only kept questions whose topic is 'other'... What am I missing?
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.read_excel('question_topics.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

questions = df['Question'].tolist()
topics = df['Topic'].tolist()
dates = df['Date'].tolist()

new_questions = []
new_topics = []
new_dates = []

for i in range(0, len(questions)):
    question = questions[i]
    topic = topics[i]
    date = dates[i]
    used_topics = []
    for j in range(i, len(questions)):
        if dates[j] > date + timedelta(days=6):
            break
        else:
            if topics[j] not in used_topics:
                used_topics.append(topics[j])
    if (topic not in used_topics or topic == 'Other') and question not in new_questions:
        new_questions.append(question)
        new_topics.append(topic)
        new_dates.append(date)

print(new_questions)
print(new_topics)
print(new_dates)
print(len(new_topics))



If two (or more) questions on the same topic are within a week of each other, which one takes precedence?

@SIGHUP I don't mind in that case; dropping either is fine.


What am I missing?

Consider simplified example
questions = ["Q1","Q2","Q3"]
for i in range(0, len(questions)):
    print("Starting processing question", questions[i])
    for j in range(i, len(questions)):
        print("Adding to exclusion topic of question", questions[j])
    print("Decision for question", questions[i])

gives output
Starting processing question Q1
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q1
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q2
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q3
Decision for question Q1
Starting processing question Q2
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q2
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q3
Decision for question Q2
Starting processing question Q3
Adding to exclusion topic of question Q3
Decision for question Q3

As you might observe you are adding topic of each question to blacklist before deciding for this question. You should ensure that you add only topics of others question, you could that by altering inner for to
for j in range(i+1, len(questions)):


You can use a sliding window.
Create a dictionary indexed by topic, with the value corresponding to the last date that topic was observed.
Iterate through the questions, first querying the last observed time for a question's topic. If the last observed date was more than one week since the question date, that topic is new, otherwise you've seen it before within a week. Update the above dictionary for the topic with the new date, and move to the next question.
